# Textbox with UTF-8 input

Tags: javascript, html, utf-8

I am in the process of internationalizing a website, and I need to allow for a user to input Chinese characters into a search textbox. This text will end up being analyzed on the backend, so I need to ensure that I can accept the text encoded as UTF-8 via javascript (everything is done through AJAX). For testing purposes, I have an alert box being popped up with the text I enter every time a search is done, and when some Chinese text is entered in, I get 'undefined' returned. With English the word I entered is returned back, as expected. How can I ensure that all text in the textbox is encoded with UTF-8?

Comment: Any code or something you would like to share with us, or maybe we should try to apply some oracle skills here? I don't remember where did I left my magic crystal ball which allows me to read other people's minds/source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure of the following:

1. Your HTML and JS documents are UTF-8 encoded.
2. You are sending a Content-type header with appropriate (UTF-8) value for both your HTML and JS files.
3. The meta tag charset defined in your HTML is also, appropriately, UTF-8.
4. Avoid using the built-in `escape` method; it is not UTF-8 (multibyte character) aware.

Comment: Since the OP says "everything is done through AJAX", does one also need to specify `Content-type:...;charset=UTF-8` among the XHR request headers?

Comment: See #2. I did not specify for the initial page request. Anytime content is requested from the server, it should be UTF-8 encoded. Anytime content is UTF-8 encoded and transferred over HTTP, an appropriate Content-type header should be specified.

Comment: As written, that seems to me to say that the HTML served for the page, and any JS served as a result of `<script src=...>` need to have that header, but does not say anything about `xhr.setRequestHeader('ContentType', ...)`.

Comment: HTTP requests without a body (e.g. every GET request, including those made to JS files or via XHR objects) shouldn't be specifying Content-type headers (although they're welcome to specify an Accept-charset header).

Comment: I assumed that he wasn't planning on sending the content of a textbox via an idempotent method, which means POST usually, which means a content body that needs to be encoded via an encoding that the server can handle.  I suppose if it's a search though, idempotent might be fine.

Comment: Perhaps you missed the part where he hasn't even gotten around to actually submitting the data before he has his error: "For testing purposes, I have an alert box being popped up with the text I enter every time a search is done, and when some Chinese text is entered in, I get 'undefined' returned."

Comment: Understood.  External input method problem.  Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score -1):

```
   <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
   </head>
```

html5

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
```

this will encode the entire page.

Comment: No it won't. It will, however, tell the browser (possibly incorrectly) that your document is UTF-8. And you never need to use the former format; HTML5 is new in name and standardization only.

Comment: i have utf8 no-bom encoded php, html and inline js in 1 file and i can js alert any chinese characters with the meta charset=utf8 tag. obviously alerting after string manipulation can throw you off, since string functions aren't mb aware, that's why there are mb_strlen etc. and obviously no one forces you to use anything..